# How do we pass two lists as the arguments of a function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

How do we pass two lists as the arguments in defining a function? I mean the two lists are arbitary, and "a real list" will be pass as the parameters during the function execution..

Is it something like

```
(define checklist
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (or (null? list1) (null? list2)) 
    #and my other work here))
```

or

```
(define (checklist list1 list2)
  (or (null? list1) (null? list2))
  #and my other work here)
```

or

```
(define checklist
  (lambda list1 list2)
  (or (null? list1) (null? list2))
  #and my other work here)
```

? I am sorry if its too basic.I've tried these but when I passed 2 lists to run the function,I got "wrong number of arguments passed" error.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third  makes a rest argument `list1` and returns the value of the global variable `list2` or an error if it doesn't exist. But giving 3+ expressions to `define` is not legal so the third won't be accepted.

Since `(define (checklist l1 l2) ...)` is just fancy way of writing `(define checklist (lambda (1 2) ...))` the two first examples are the exact same.

Note that `(or x y z)` will evaluate to the first true value and if you have expressions after it becomes dead code. If you were expecting to do something if or if not `(or x y z)` were true or not you need to use a conditional like `(if (or x y z) something-expression something-else-expression)`

Comment: Thank you very much! So its fine to use the first one or the second one and I just need to modify my or part,right?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention you @Sylwester?

Comment: @lilyniall Yes. You need to use the result for something. eg in an `if` or as the tail expression so it's the returned value. If you need to use it more than once you can bind it to a name with `let`.